# NUnit: Get testname in setup method

Tags: nunit

In NUnit I'm able to define a Setup method via the `[Setup]` attribute. The method has the signature `public void Setup()`. Is it possible to get the testname for that the `Setup` method is designated for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In NUnit 3.x, just use `TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name`. There are also other properties on `Test` like `MethodName` or `FullName` depending on what you need.

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestNameInSetup
{
    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        var testName = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name;
        TestContext.WriteLine($"SetUp for {testName}");
    }

    [Test]
    public void NamedTest()
    {
        var testName = TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name;
        TestContext.WriteLine($"Running test {testName}");
    }
}
```